# Change slideDown Menu into Multi-column

Tags: jquery, menu, multiple-columns

This is what I've got.

http://jsfiddle.net/0bm9vf1y/

It's working just fine, but there's been a sudden change of plans and I have to change the way it works.

I want to keep the same behavior (slideUp / slideDown) but instead of the submenus sliding down just below their respective menu I need them to slide down on a 2nd column. I'm actually gonna have at least 3 columns, but the behavior is the same.

[image]

I've looked for a jQuery plugin but couldn't find anything remotely similar.

Does anybody know of one? or a simple fix to my current situation...

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 1-A</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 1-B</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 2-A</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 2-B</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 3-A</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 3-B</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 3-C</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 3-D</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 4-A</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 4-B</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
  $('.submenu').hide();
  $('.menu').on('click', function(){
    if(!($(this).children('.submenu').is(':visible'))){
      $('.submenu').slideUp();
      $(this).children('.submenu').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('.submenu').slideUp();
    }
  });
$('.submenu').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define submenus in seperate div's with unique id's, with subitems.

Place the div in each columns first.

Make them show/hide from parent item.

You need to add some div's to your html to place subitems and toggle them.

Hopes this helps you back on track, i don't have much time now, maybe later.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I'm able to do it from scratch myself. Do you not have an example/demo? I don't think this is something never done before but I've googled, googled and googled and found... nothing! :(

Comment: wrap subitems( <li class="submenu">Item 1-A</li>
  <li class="submenu">Item 1-B</li>) in another div that's hidden by default. when "Item 1" is pressed show the div with the subitems. remember to also add a new "ul" beteen the div and li's.

Comment: In other words, your already have the functionality but need to present it somewhere else. And for that you need some div's where you can display them. Sorry again I can only lead you in a way and inpiring you/others for now.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. ;) I've been beating my head against the wall for a while and still couldn't crack it... Here's where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/0bm9vf1y/9/